# check visibilty of specific product

Tags: magento-1.9, database, attributes, product-attribute, query

I want to select a value for status or visibility on a specific product for which I have only the sku.  I have tried many ways but did not arrive a a solution to the problem.  Anyone can help me, thanks in advance

I found this in Magento Forum that may be helpful

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE attribute_id = (
SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 2
```

Comment: Do you want SQL or Magento code?

Comment: If possible both , but I prefer SQL code ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To verify the visibility of product (either it is visible in catalog or search) you can use the `$product->getData('visibility')` method. It will give a numeric value which is set as a constant in \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility

In product EAV it is represented by the attribute with code 'visibility' so you can make a inner join using product and the eav table like:

```
SELECT cpei.value FROM catalog_product_entity as cpe
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int as cpei ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.row_id
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute as ea ON ea.attribute_id = cpei.attribute_id
WHERE cpe.sku = {YOUR SKU GOES HERE} AND ea.attribute_code = 'visibility';
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco but it is showing an error

Comment: this line causes an error  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int as cpei ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.row_id exactly in row_id

Comment: Are you using magento 2 or magento 1? Try to change row_id for entity_id

Comment: I am using magento 1

Comment: Ahmed, changing row_id for entity_id worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [enabled Flat Product Tables](https://www.atensoftware.com/p90.php?q=315), you can query those tables directly, using the `visibility` column for your condition.  The names of the table(s) will depend on how many stores you have, but it will look similar to this: catalog_product_flat_**1** for your default store, catalog_product_flat_**2** for the second store that you created, catalog_product_flat_**3** for the third, and so forth.

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT sku, visibility
FROM catalog_product_flat_1
WHERE visibility in (2, 4);
```

**Note:**  I added a condition for the visibility values which will include those shown in categories/other default pages, the possible values are as follows:

```
1    Not Visible Individually
2    Visible in Catalog Only
3    Visible in Search Only
4    Visible in Catalog AND Search
```